# Python logging: Create new log file if it is deleted while program is running (RotatingFileHandler)

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a python program running which is continuously logging to a file using a TimedRotatingFileHandler. From time to time i want to get the log files **without** closing the program so i simply cut & paste the log files to a different location.

The program doesn't crash if i do this but doesn't log to any file anymore either.

After looking at the source code of [BaseRotatingFileHandler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L47):

```
def emit(self, record):
    try:
        if self.shouldRollover(record):
            self.doRollover()
        logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)
    except Exception:
        self.handleError(record)
```

i figured i could subclass TimedRotatingFileHandler and reimplement its emit function like this:

```
def emit(self, record):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(self.baseFilename) or self.shouldRollover(record):
            self.doRollover()
        logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)
    except Exception:
        self.handleError(record)
```

The following snippet seems to achieve what i want. But i am not sure if my approach is the best way to solve my problem. Is there a better way to achieve this or am i doing it right?

```js
import logging.handlers
import logging
import time
import os


class TimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(filename, **kwargs)

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(self.baseFilename) or self.shouldRollover(record):
                self.doRollover()
            logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)


logging.basicConfig(handlers = [TimedRotatingFileHandler('test.log')])

for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    logging.critical('test')
```

**EDIT:**

I applied the solution provided by @danny. In order to keep the RotatingFileHandler capabilites i created a hybrid class of TimedRotatingFileHandler and WatchedFileHandler:

```
class WatchedTimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler, logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(filename, **kwargs)
        self.dev, self.ino = -1, -1
        self._statstream()

    def emit(self, record):
        self.reopenIfNeeded()
        super().emit(record)
```

Comment: The ecfect of changing a file that was opened by an other process depend on the OS, the file system, the open mode and some other things.

Comment: as danny rightly concluded im on linux

Comment: i noticed that the constructor for WatchedFileHandler is never called... so you copied those lines of code into your constructor... very clever. does this code behave as you expected/wanted/needed?

Comment: thats correct.
yes, it worked at the time. it is not guaranteed to work in the future (or present?) though

Comment: @johnson  Can you explain bit about self.dev, self.ino = -1, -1 & self._statstream() & reOpenIfNeeded ? or can you please direct me to some resource ?

Comment: You have to look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#watchedfilehandler) and/or the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/67acf74c4eaf64a860cc1bcda6efe6e9cb01f89b/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L423)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since opened files cannot be changed on Windows platform, safe to say the OP is not looking for a cross platform solution.

In that case, [`logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#watchedfilehandler) is an appropriate solution to logging continuing when the file being logged to is changed.

From docs:

> The WatchedFileHandler class, located in the logging.handlers module,
>   is a FileHandler which watches the file it is logging to. If the file
>   changes, it is closed and reopened using the file name.

There is no rotating *and* watched file handler available so will have to move rotating to `logrotate` or similar with this solution.

Alternatively use your patch to `TimedRotatingHandler` which will need to close and re-open the file handle correctly in addition to the code you have already, to match what `WatchedFileHandler` does.

Answer (score 0):

The most cross-platform way to handle it is to only take the "old" files, leaving the most recent file in place.
This will work even without changing the handler implementation and will not fail under different platforms.